# SMS third-party platform for Xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, sms

I am creating a Xamarin.ios application in the app i like to send notification's through sms by selected contact list. Any suggestions about SMS third-party platform to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to implement them for Xamarin.iOS app, you can refer to the Xamarin documentations here:

- [Send an SMS or
  iMessage](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/shared_resources/sms/send_an_sms_or_imessage/)
- [Choose a Contact](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/shared_resources/contacts/choose_a_contact/)
- [Contacts and ContactsUI](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/contacts/)

For Xamarin.forms for all platforms, here's two related third-party:

- [ContactsPlugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ContactsPlugin)
- [Xam.Plugins.Messaging](https://github.com/cjlotz/Xamarin.Plugins)

Answer (score -1):

There is an alternative solution to the one on the Xamarin site, using the `MessageUI`. It provides more flexibility as you can specify multiple recipients and an SMS body. From what I've experienced is seems to launch faster too.

Example code:

```
if (MFMessageComposeViewController.CanSendText)
{
    var smsViewController = new MFMessageComposeViewController()
    {
        Body = "An SMS with content!",
        Recipients = new string[] { number },

    };

    smsViewController.Finished += (sender, e) =>
        this.DismissViewController(true, null);


    this.PresentViewController(smsViewController, true, null);
}
```

Remember that SMS is not supported on the Simulator. The `CanSendText` property of `MFMessageComposeViewController` will alway return `false`.

This will only work on a device.